# Ceph Disaster Recovery Solution

Tags: ceph

I m sitting up a new cluster , i would like to set up another cluster and enable sync between the two, the second cluster work as disater recovery.

i'm new to Ceph and i'm not sure how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Disaster recovery in Ceph depends on how you are using Ceph and what exactly your requirements for disaster recovery are. Since Jewel there are two options.

For RBD you can use rbd-mirroring (http://docs.ceph.com/docs/mimic/rbd/rbd-mirroring/). Mirroring can be enabled based on pools and will invoke the rbd-mirror daemon. With rbd-mirroring enabled writes will go into the rbd image journal first, after that the write will be acknowledged to the client and then written to image itself. The rbd-mirror daemon will replay the image journal to your remote location.

Additiontally for radaosgw multisite is available: http://docs.ceph.com/docs/mimic/radosgw/multisite/.

For CephFS there is no such kind of solution available yet.